# RoR image tag not finding image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I have an image in the asset pipeline like this: "app/assets/images/wholesale_analysis.png".  In my template, I have this tag `<%= image_tag("wholesale_analysis.png") %>`, however it is not finding the image.  It returns the text for the image tag instead of the image even if I provide an 'alt:' in the image tag.  The image tag works in the layout, but not in the template.  What is going on?

@Kamil  Results of rails console...

```
`C:/Users/CMMC/Documents/Sites/cmmc/config/environments/development.rb:50:in 

block in <top (required)>': undefined method `config' for #<Rack::Sendfile:0x5321250> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:209:in `configure'
        from C:/Users/CMMC/Documents/Sites/cmmc/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:600:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:599:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/CMMC/Documents/Sites/cmmc/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:157:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:77:in `console'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you run it locally or on test/production env?

Comment: It's in the development environment.

Comment: Start rails console (`rails c`) and get value of: Rails.application.config.assets.precompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem...my file was just named .html instead of .html.erb.  Everything works now! Thank you for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space of the filename between "wholesale" and "analysis.png", as in: wholesale_analysis.png or wholesaleanalysis.png
and change your image tag as well:

```
<%= image_tag("wholesale_analysis.png") %>
```

Comment: @Jessica did you also remove the space from the file name in the images folder?

Comment: Yes I did.  I replaced them with an underscore.

Comment: did you remove the space between image_tag and the parenthesis as well? check the code example.

Comment: Try placing your image in this folder: /app/assets/yourimagehere.png and don't change the image_tag code, leave it like <%= image_tag("wholesale_analysis.png") %> . Rails documentation mentions that Rails will look into assets folder for the image: image_tag("rails.png") # => <img alt="Rails" src="/assets/rails.png" />. It should work anyway if it's inside images folder, but try placing it in assets to check it out. Also, have you checked if a different image works?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to put images in your /public direcotry as they should not be precompiled like css and js files. 
If you really want to have them in your assets, you should try: `<%= image_tag("/assets/wholesale_analysis.png") %>`

Comment: I tried both suggestions...putting the image in the public directory and changing the image tag to include "/assets/".  Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

@Xenedra place the image in assets/ folder and let the tag be

```
<%= image_tag("wholesale_analysis.png") %>
```

Comment: try to precompile the assets using rake assets:precompile, jus give a try